# In what cases is there no process on Android when calling ActivityManager's getRunningAppProcesses method

Tags: android

Android's ActivityManager implements [`getRunningAppProcesses`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses()).

> Returns a list of application processes that are running on the device.
>
> Note: this method is only intended for debugging or building a user-facing process management UI.
>
> Returns a list of RunningAppProcessInfo records, or **null if there are no running processes** (it will not return an empty list). This list ordering is not specified.

I want to understand the case where **there are no processes running, when does this happen?** This is odd, because if this method is called (i.e. in any app), there'd be at least 1 process running, the app itself.